# I am sending emails by using data extension. Email not sent for all the users in the data extension out of 100% only 80% users email being sent

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am sending emails by using data extension. Email not sent for all the users in the data extension out of 100% only 80% users email being sent. All the emails are active emails only there is no unsubscribe emails.What is reason please help me.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314485&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it's due to **List Detective** and the **Subscriber status**.

Marketing Cloud will not send (by default) to certain Email addresses and domains, and any Subscriber in your Data Extension having this kind of an Email address will be excluded from the Send entirely.

Typical ones excluded are like info@...., admin@...., sales@.... etc

The other reason is status. They may have unsubscribed from your previous Emails or they may be in Held status due to soft bounces. Or there may also have been some typos with some Email addresses (like `@` missing or suffix is written like `.c0m`)

Comment: Also check for duplicates if you have dedupe by email address checked.